# Laravel Eloquent query returning only one row from the database table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I made this code from a project I'm currently developing at work. The problem I'm having is that this code:

```
php
public function getAllEstaciones(Request $request){
  $estaciones = Estacion::select('IdEstacion', 'proyectoplanning.NombreProyectoPlanning', 'modeloequipo.NombreModeloEquipo', 
  'tipoinstalacion.NombreTipoInstalacion', 'estacion.IdEstadoGeneral', 'estadogeneral.NombreEstadoGeneral', 
  'mediotransmision.NombreMedioTransmision', 'propietarioestacion.NombrePropietarioEstacion', 'centropoblado.NombreCentroPoblado', 
  'distrito.NombreDistrito', 'provincia.NombreProvincia', 'departamento.NombreDepartamento', 'tiposervicio.NombreTipoServicio', 'estacion.IdBtsEstacion', 
  'btsestacion.Direccion', 'CodigoPresupuestalPlanning', 'CodigoUnicoPlanning', 'Prioridad', 'LatitudPlanning', 'LongitudPlanning',
  'distrito.NombreDistrito', 'provincia.NombreProvincia', 'departamento.NombreDepartamento', 'tiposervicio.NombreTipoServicio', 
  'estacion.IdBtsEstacion', 'btsestacion.Direccion', 'CodigoPresupuestalPlanning', 'CodigoUnicoPlanning', 'Prioridad', 
  'LatitudPlanning', 'LongitudPlanning')
  ->join('proyectoplanning', 'proyectoplanning.IdProyectoPlanning', '=', 'estacion.IdProyectoPlanning')
  ->join('modeloequipo', 'modeloequipo.IdModeloEquipo', '=', 'estacion.IdModeloEquipo')
  ->join('tipoinstalacion', 'tipoinstalacion.IdTipoInstalacion', '=', 'estacion.IdTipoInstalacion')
  ->join('estadogeneral', 'estadogeneral.IdEstadoGeneral', '=', 'estacion.IdEstadoGeneral')
  ->join('mediotransmision', 'mediotransmision.IdMedioTransmision', '=', 'estacion.IdMedioTransmision')
  ->join('propietarioestacion', 'propietarioestacion.IdPropietarioEstacion', '=', 'estacion.IdPropietarioEstacion')
  ->join('centropoblado', 'centropoblado.IdCentroPoblado', '=', 'estacion.IdCentroPoblado')
  ->join('distrito', 'distrito.IdDistrito', '=', 'centropoblado.IdDistrito')
  ->join('provincia', 'provincia.IdProvincia', '=', 'distrito.IdProvincia')
  ->join('departamento', 'departamento.IdDepartamento', '=', 'provincia.IdDepartamento')
  ->join('tiposervicio', 'tiposervicio.IdTipoServicio', '=', 'estacion.IdTipoServicio')
  ->join('btsestacion', 'btsestacion.IdBtsEstacion', '=', 'estacion.IdBtsEstacion')
  ->get();
  return response()->json($estaciones);
}
```

This is a query I built using the Eloquent module form Laravel. It's only returning one row from the table "Estaciones". I tried doing `$estaciones = DB::table("estacion")` with no success. I'd be grateful if you guys could give me some insight.

Comment: Can you run the raw query against your database and see how many rows it returns? Instead of calling `->get()` at the end call `->toSql()`.  With Joins if one of your rows has a null value on one of the joins those rows will not show.  There are a lot of joins here. The problem may just be that you only have 1 row that meets this criteria

Comment: Remove all Joins and them put one by one, you'll see where is the problem.

Comment: it never even crossed my mind to try the query on the db engine. it is actually returning 1 row. thanks a lot. ill go check what is the field that is causing the problems.

Comment: you're welcome friend.

Comment: To debug queries, and other things, it is very useful the package `laravel-debugbar`, should be a must on development.

Comment: Agreed with ajon and JoaoGRRR , best way is to debug large queries is in to  execute first in sql engine.

Comment: From what I see you're dealing with ONE or MANY tables that has only ONE record to your main table `estacion` or other related table. It's time for you to check on LEFT JOIN and RIGHT JOIN, so that records from a Right table that are not related to a Left table also appear in results

Comment: See it that way. Let's say you have `song` table related to parent tables `artist` and `genre`. If ALL song records `artists_id` are specified and only ONE song record `genre_id` is specified, then if you use `->join('artist', ...` and `->join('genre', ...` then only ONE song record will be returned. But using `->leftJoin('genre', ...) will display ALL song records and will display `genre_id` NULL on records that do not have a genre.